# Django ManyToMany access in save() function

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I want to create additional objects based on user input during the .save() method of my model. the info is stored in a ManyToMany-relation `.available_specs`.

My code works, if one presses save twice, but not at the first time. The problem is described in the comments here [Django foreign key access in save() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307038/django-foreign-key-access-in-save-function), too.

Here is what I do:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

    my_save_result = super().save(*args, **kwargs) #save first to create an id
    self.refresh_from_db() #just as a test, did not help at all

    #the following line is the problem: 
    #   in the first save, available_specs.all() returns []
    #   when I re-open the model and save again, I get the correct list
    for spec in self.available_specs.all():
        VehicleSpec.objects.get_or_create(vehicle=self, spec=spec)

    return my_save_result
```

I'm using Python 3.5 and Django 1.9

**Edit:**
I tried to use the `post_save()` signal using the following code (and removed the overridden save()-method):

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=VehicleModel)
def create_dependent_vehicle_specs(sender, **kwargs):
    vehicle = kwargs['instance']

    #in the first save-process I get an empty list here, 
    #after I hit save again, the code works. 
    print(vehicle, vehicle.available_specs.all())
    for spec in vehicle.available_specs.all():
        VehicleSpec.objects.get_or_create(vehicle=vehicle, spec=spec)
```

**Edit2:** m2m_changed did the trick:

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=VehicleModel)
def create_dependent_vehicle_specs(sender, **kwargs):
    vehicle = kwargs['instance']
    for spec in vehicle.available_specs.all():
        VehicleSpec.objects.get_or_create(vehicle=vehicle, spec=spec)

m2m_changed.connect(create_dependent_vehicle_specs, sender=VehicleModel.available_specs.through)  # @UndefinedVariable
```

BTW: A related question is here: [Django accessing ManyToMany fields from post_save signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23795811/django-accessing-manytomany-fields-from-post-save-signal)

Comment: Did you try doing it in [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#post-save) signal?

Comment: I just tried it with same effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [`m2m_changed` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#m2m-changed). You should not be calling another models' `get_or_create` in another models' save method